# Why is my counter not counting and my ArrayList not adding in the new integer values into the array?

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, increment

The primary source of my issues is coming from my method "add" and the array "mathAnswers" and the counter "score."

I am trying to compare array values, make them perform a mathematical function, and then check to see if the user input matches the answer. I also want the correct answer to be added to an array, and then print out that array, along with the counter verifying the users score.

I'm running into an issue where my counter isn't incrementing, my values aren't inputting into my array, and everything remains 0. Here is my code.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Program7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] mathQuizLeft = {
                8,  //0
                14, //1
                16, //2
                8,  //3
                17, //4
                5,  //5
                27, //6
                4,  //7
                20, //8
                13, //9
        };

        int [] mathQuizRight = {
                13, //0
                12, //1
                4,  //2
                18, //3
                4,  //4
                4,  //5
                9,  //6
                7,  //7
                4,  //8
                4,  //9
        };


        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        double userAns = 0;
        double answer = 6;

        System.out.println("Welcome to the 3rd Grade Math Quiz. \n");
        System.out.println("The Quiz begins now: \n"
                + "1. 8 - 13\n2. 14 + 12\n3. 16 / 4\n4. 8 + 18\n5. 17 % 4\n6. 5 x 4\n"
                + "7. 27 / 9\n8. 4 - 7\n9. 20 x 4\n10. 13 - 4");

        for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            if (i < 10) {
                System.out.printf("%d. ", (i + 1));
                userAns = Double.valueOf(scanner.nextDouble());
                add(mathQuizLeft, mathQuizRight, i, answer, userAns);
            }
            else {
                add(mathQuizLeft, mathQuizRight, i, answer, userAns);
            }
        }
    }



    public static void add(int[] array1, int[] array2, int i, double answer, double userAns) {
        ArrayList<Integer> mathAnswers = new ArrayList<>(); //for storing functions

        int score = 0;

        if (i == 1 || i == 3) { //addition
            answer = array1[i] + array2[i];
            if (userAns == answer) {
                score++;
                mathAnswers.add(i);
            }
        } else if (i == 0 || i == 7 || i == 9) { //subtraction
            answer = array1[i] - array2[i];
            if (userAns == answer) {
                score++;
                mathAnswers.add(i);
            }
        } else if (i == 5 || i == 8) { //multiplication
            answer = array1[i] - array2[i];
            if (userAns == answer) {
                score++;
                mathAnswers.add(i);
            }
        } else if (i == 2 || i == 6) { //multiplication
            answer = array1[i] - array2[i];
            if (userAns == answer) {
                score++;
                mathAnswers.add(i);
            }
        } else if (i == 4) { //multiplication
            answer = array1[i] - array2[i];
            if (userAns == answer) {
                score++;
                mathAnswers.add(i);
            }
        } else if (i == 10) {
            for (double array: mathAnswers) {
                System.out.println(array);
            }
            System.out.println(score);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand this question, but it isn't clear which counter you are talking about or which array needs to be updated. It may be that you simply have to learn to set breakpoints and step through your code to see what is happening.

Comment: Sorry about that. My counter "score" and my array "mathAnswers". I will update that in my question. I'm currently having trouble pulling the values from my array in mathAnswers. I'm still testing and trying to find out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Your misstake is in the add() method. You count after each right answer the score and add i to the ArrayList, but you doesn't safe the arraylist and the score. You have to declare the ArrayList and the score global or you have to return it and save it in the main()-method.

```
public class Program7 {
  private static int score = 0;
  private static ArrayList<Integer> mathAnswers = new ArrayList<>();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
  }

  public static void add(...) {
    if(...) {
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue. I may just end up deleting this but I had to play with the method a lot to figure out what would get it to increment and add the value to the array. I ended up using an ArrayList to add the values for it instead of a primitive array. I ended up rewriting the whole method but I ended up getting it to work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Program7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] mathQuizLeft = {
                8,  //0
                14, //1
                16, //2
                8,  //3
                17, //4
                5,  //5
                27, //6
                4,  //7
                20, //8
                13, //9
        };

        int [] mathQuizRight = {
                13, //0
                12, //1
                4,  //2
                18, //3
                4,  //4
                4,  //5
                9,  //6
                7,  //7
                4,  //8
                4,  //9
        };

        int score = 0;
        int userAns = 0;
        int answer = 0;

        System.out.println("Welcome to the 3rd Grade Math Quiz. \n");
        System.out.println("The Quiz begins now: \n"
                + "1. 8 - 13\n2. 14 + 12\n3. 16 / 4\n4. 8 + 18\n5. Remainder of 17 / 4\n6. 5 x 4\n"
                + "7. 27 / 9\n8. 4 - 7\n9. 20 x 4\n10. 13 - 4");

        add(mathQuizLeft, mathQuizRight, answer, score, userAns);

    }

    public static void add(int[] array1, int[] array2, int answer, int score, int userAns) {
        ArrayList<Integer> mathAnswers = new ArrayList<>(); //for storing functions
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        answer = 0;
        score = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            if(i == 10) {
                break;
            }

            if (i == 1 || i == 3) { //addition
                answer = array1[i] + array2[i];
            } else if (i == 0 || i == 7 || i == 9) { //subtraction
                answer = array1[i] - array2[i];
            } else if (i == 5 || i == 8) { //multiplication
                answer = array1[i] * array2[i];
            } else if (i == 2 || i == 6) { //division
                answer = array1[i] / array2[i];
            } else { //modulo
                answer = array1[i] % array2[i];
            }

            System.out.printf("%d. ", (i + 1));
            userAns = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextInt());

            mathAnswers.add(answer);

            if (userAns == answer) {
                score++;
            }

            System.out.println(score);
            System.out.println(mathAnswers.get(i));
        }

        if (score >= 7) {
            System.out.println("Your score was: " + score + " - You passed!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Your score was: " + score + " - Please Try again.");
        }
    }
}
```